# Checking if dates are equal with linq to ef

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to check if a `DateTime` is already in my db.

I've broken up the code below in order to get a better understanding of what's going on but despite my best efforts, dateChecks will always return an empty list.

```
    var MyDate = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var milestone in mtMilestone.Milestones)
    {

        var checkIfAlreadyPulled = _ipdb.JsonDataReleases.
            Where(x => x.ReleaseId == mtMilestone.ReleaseId).ToList();

        var dateChecks = checkIfAlreadyPulled.
            Where(x => EntityFunctions.Equals(x.LastUpdated, MyDate)).ToList();

        if (!dateChecks.Any())
        {
            /* do stuff what this does it it makes a new entry into the JsonDataReleases 
            db using MyDate as the new LastUpdated value. */ 
        }

        /* Does more unrelated stuff... */

    }
```

EDIT: So I figured it out!

Turns out that when the DateTime.Now was being saved as the LastUpdated value in the sql db, it cuts off the milliseconds.

```
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var MyDate= new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `LastUpdated` field stores date & time, your `Where` clause will only select items with the same exact date & time of your `MyDate`. If you're just comparing dates, you need to compare the  `.Date` on each side:

```
var dateChecks = checkIfAlreadyPulled.
    Where(x => x.LastUpdated.Date == MyDate.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: I would prefer it being as specific as possible, so comparing DateTimes is fine. (And yes both are full DateTime objects)

Comment: So if the `LastUpdated` time is 9:01.23432323, your `MyDate` field is going to specifically ask for that date? If so then your code is working as expected. If not, provide some examples of the `MyDate` field and values in the `LastUpdated`.

Comment: Based on what you said, I made some changes to check and ensure the values were correct and now I'm pretty confused. I'm going to update the post with additional information.

Comment: I'll give you credit since you convinced me to double check that the values were indeed the same. I wasn't aware that the DateTime sql field isn't as precise as the c# DateTime object.